# mySQL MATCH AGAINST with contained strings

Tags: mysql, sql, database, match

So i have a problem with mysqls match against.

I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT somefield FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(somefield) AGAINST ('some 2 x 3');
```

Where "some 2 x 3" is the thing i'm searching for. But the problem is mysql searches for each word so it will search for 'some', '2', 'x' and '3' and as I can't change ft_min_word_len in my mysql settings this just doesn't work and ignores anything less that 2 characters.

So what i want to do is group the '2 x 3' bit in the query. 
So it could come out like this???

```
SELECT somefield FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(somefield) AGAINST ('some {2 x 3}');
```

This would search for 'some' and '2 x 3'

Is the possible if so how could i do it?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that fulltext isn't the right solution for your request. MySQL won't index the phrase `2 x 3` and even not the word `some`, because it is on stop words list. I suggest you to extend the query with `OR somefield LIKE '%some 2 x 3%'` clause to handle these cases where fulltext search is not enough.

Comment: This is that i was going to say :P

Comment: Ok then it's a bad example 'some' is not what i was actually searching for. It will be a word thats not on the stop words list. 'Some' was a placeholder name.

Comment: If it indexes the words but not the number would is be a good idea to mix 

SELECT somefield FROM my_table WHERE MATCH(somefield) AGAINST ('something') and somefield LIKE '%2 x 4%';

As that doesn't give me amazing results. Not in the order of relevance that the MATCH AGAINST gave me.

Comment: I use this approach on one quite popular sharing website based on searching: `SELECT *, MATCH(somefield) AGAINST ('something') AS relevance FROM ft_table WHERE MATCH(somefield) AGAINST ('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR somefield LIKE '%something%' ORDER BY relevance DESC`. Just pay attention on BOOLEAN mode since it is worth to write some simple pre-processor which converts user inputted query to boolean logic (see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)).